# Screen to show app output inside app in android

Tags: android

I'm writing an android app just to get familiar with the OS and API. I'd like to show what my app is doing to the user in a seperate screen and not via notifications. The reason is that I'd like to show the user exactly what the app is querying and how long it took etc. I saw an example of this in the superuser app which shows what the app is doing when it is updating itself.

- Is there a library to do this?
- Is it as simple as just showing a text box and then populating it programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have done it so..
Just push state changes to your UI thread and display them there.
You can do that via [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html), which is intended to let background services communicate with UI activities, or [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) which is simpler version of the previous.

Here on StackOverflow you will find dozens of questions describing how to implement it.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't clear but I was looking for mainly UI side code.